# What is the "camera looking object" and two rectangular objects on my Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

What is the little camera looking thing at the bottom left of my Nintendo Switch's screen? What about the two little rectangles that are also located at the bottom left and right?

Comment: Any screenshots of what you are asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this graph from [Nintendo](https://www.nintendo.com.au/nintendo-switch/specs/#1) on the parts of the Switch: [image: Switch Anatomy]

The **two little rectangles on the bottom left and right hand corner are speakers**, and the **little lens-like piece in the middle of the Switch is the brightness detector**, which lowers the brightness of the screen depending on the detected light in the area.

Answer (score 2):

The camera looking object is a brightness sensor, and the two rectangular objects are speakers.

Source is from [Nintendo's website](https://www.nintendo.com.au/nintendo-switch/specs/#1).

[image: Switch screen]